# I can't trade a Powersave Mew to my friend, why?

Tags: cheats, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have a Powersaved Mew that I'm trying to trade to a friend of mine (He's registered in my DS).

We have Alpha Saphire and are both finished the game, the mew is level 15 with no HM moves learned. We're not using Wondertrade or GTS. I keep getting a message saying "There's a Pokemon that can't be traded in your party" (I've tried trading it from my party and from a box neither works.

[image: Mew's Info]

Why can't I trade it?

Comment: Have you changed its IVs, EVs? What's listed on the info page? I mean, the encounter location, or the game where you've obtained it.

Answer (score 1):

In short; Your hacked Mew failed to pass some hack detection.

There are a [limited number of sources](http://www.serebii.net/events/dex/151.shtml) for Mew, and other mythical legendaries that are distribution only, and most of them have tell-tale stats that can be checked against.

Namely, from what you've shown; the Original Trainer (OT) and ID No. do not match any distribution (There was a 2005 distribution that would have a non-predefined Trainer/ID, but that mew would be lvl 30+) and the Pokeball (either a quickball or regular pokeball) also causes it to not match any distribution.

There are other things that could be wrong with it: IVS, EVs, Encounter location, Game obtained, Ribbon...

Suffice it to say, if you used your cheating device to just encounter a mew (or any other distribution-only), and you catch it, it is probably not going to pass hack-detection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Mew's ball is a normal Pokeball (as you can see it's shifted to the right), the Quickball is used by another pokemon imho.

Comment: @pinckerman Oh, yeah, I see now... two Pokemon in the party, one's in a quickball, the other is mew. Doesn't change much though, there are relatively few legit mews that come in a regular pokeball, few of them below lvl 15, and none of those match the trainer/ID

Comment: How would I be able to fix it? Can I change the pokeball into a cherish ball, and find a way to change the player ID would that work?

Comment: @LucasScarola it's a start - depending on which event you are trying to pass it off as, you may also need to give it a premier or classic ribbon, and set its encounter location and game obtained. Also - there are technically two IDs, the 5 digit one we see, and a secondary hidden one. so even if you change the ID, it might not match.